# AWS console test user is not able to see admin user lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

For example I am admin of AWS console and there is a user X to whom I need to share some test lambda functions which are created by me, so that he can test in test lambda functions instead of messing with production lambda functions and also I do not want X to see access my lambda functions.

But when I create a test user and login into his console, I am not able to see any of the admin functions in his console, below is my custom policy attached to the test user

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "cognito-identity:ListIdentityPools",
                "cognito-sync:GetCognitoEvents",
                "cognito-sync:SetCognitoEvents",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "events:*",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:*",
                "kms:ListAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

but the same thing does not happened with s3 buckets, I have attached one more policy to the test user for accessing only test s3 bucket, which is working well, below is the policy description.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try only adding Lamda policy, like you did to validate S3? I understand the original policy has granted access to lambda.

Comment: Could it be due to the fact the your resource (lambda function) policies are  different from IAM policy for this user?

Comment: What sort user is your test user? Admin (or) non-admin? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html#access-policy-examples-for-sdk-cli

Comment: @Nambari test User is non-admin with the above policies attached to the user

Comment: @Nambari I have attached the lambda policy did not miss that, your reasoning might be correct about resource policies but isn't it weird that other user can't access another users lambda functions, isn't there a solution for it, thanks

Comment: @Nambari I made a silly mistake, see the solution for more information

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this issue. Accept your answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a silly mistake, some one also might encounter it, so I would like to mention it, I have selected a different region in my aws console in testuser account, so it is not showing up, when I select back the region where I have created the lmabda functions it started showing up all the lambda functions.